# Handle the error when the limits do not exist in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I have been having a problem with SymPy at the time of making a limit which would have to answer "does not exist" is returning the infinite value. The code section would be this:

```
x = Symbol ('x')
a = Limit ((5-x) / (x-2), x, 2, "+"). doit ()
print (a)
oo
b = Limit ((5-x) / (x-2), x, 2, "-"). doit ()
print (b)
-oo
c = Limit ((5-x) / (x-2), x, 2) .doit ()
print (c)
oo
```

Here is the problem as investigated and check should leave a message as the limit does not exist or return any value equal to 0.

Comment: x = Symbol ('x')
a = Limit ((5-x) / (x-2), x, 2, "+"). doit ()
print (a)
oo
b = Limit ((5-x) / (x-2), x, 2, "-"). doit ()
print (b)
-oo
c = Limit ((5-x) / (x-2), x, 2) .doit ()
print (c)
oo here is the problem as investigated and check should leave a message as the limit does not exist or return any value equal to 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `Limit ((5-x) / (x-2), x, 2)`  means one-sided limit from the right, so `c` will always be the same as `a` in your example.

In the current development version on GitHub, one can pass `"+-"` as the direction, which will compute both limits and raise ValueError if they are not the same:

```
>>> limit((5-x) / (x-2), x, 2, "+-")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/sympy/sympy/series/limits.py", line 66, in limit
    % (llim, rlim))
ValueError: The limit does not exist since left hand limit = -oo and right hand limit = oo
```

But you probably just want a conditional like

```
if a != b: 
    print("One-sided limits are different")
elif a.is_infinite:
    print("Infinite limit")
# and so on
```